# Commutator of $A_5$

Tags: group-theory

I don't understand this question can someone explain what does it mean as commutator in $S_5$.

Exhibit a representative of each cycle type of $A_5$ as a commutator in $S_5$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A commutator is an element of the form $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$ (for $x,y\in G$ for some group $G$). This question is asking: given $\sigma\in A_5$, write $\sigma=\tau\beta\tau^{-1}\beta^{-1}$ for some $\tau,\beta\in S_5$.